# Does this define a Ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups

I am working on some rings practice questions and I have come across one where I am having a bit of difficulty with checking some of the ring axioms:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, let $ C(G) = \{ f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}
>  \} $ with addition given by
>
> $$(f+g) = f(x) + g(x) $$ and multiplication $$ (f*g)(x) = \sum_{y \in
>  G} f(xy^{-1})g(y) $$

Is this a ring?

Going through the addition axioms, they all seem to pass:

(1) Addition is closed since, if $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}$ and $g(x) \in \mathbb{C}$ then $f(x) + g(x) \in \mathbb{C}$

(2) Addition is commutative since if $f(x) + g(x) = (a+bi) + (c+di) $ then by the commutativity of $\mathbb{C} \implies g(x) + f(x) = (a+bi) + (c+di) $

(3) I check $ (f(x) + g(x)) + h(x)  = f(x) + (g(x) + h(x)) $ similarly.

(4) There exists a zero element by defining it as the zero map, then $f(x) + 0 = f(x) \in \mathbb{c}$

(5) Each function $f(x)$ has an inverse defined by $-f(x)$

I think I have done the above correctly, but I start to have a bit of trouble with the multiplication axioms.

(1) $f(x) * g(x) $ is closed since:

$$f(x) * g(x) = \sum_{y \in G} f(xy^{-1})g(y) = f(xy_1^{-1})g(y_1) +...+f(xy_n^{-1})g(y_n)  $$ where each term in the summation is a multiplication of complex numbers, and addition is closed under the complex numbers.

(2) Checking associativity gets a bit complicated, I have:

$$[(f*g)(x)]*h = [\sum_{y \in G} f(xy^{-1})g(y)]*h(x) = [f(xy_1^{-1})g(y_1) +...+f(xy_n^{-1})g(y_n)]*h(x) = f(xy_1^{-1})g(y_1)*h(x) +...+f(xy_n^{-1})g(y_n)*h(x) = $$

$$\sum_{y_i \in G} f(xy_1^{-1}y_i^{-1})g(y_1)h(y_i)+...+ \sum_{y_i \in G} f(xy_n^{-1}y_i^{-1})g(y_n)h(y_i)$$

I'm not even sure if I have done the multiplication correctly?

On the other hand:

$$f*[(g*h)(x)] = f*[\sum_{y \in G} g(xy^{-1})h(y)] = f(x)*[g(xy_1^{-1})h(y_1) +...+g(xy_n^{-1})h(y_n)] = f(x)*g(xy_1^{-1})h(y_1)+...+f(x)*g(xy_n^{-1})h(y_n) = $$

$$\sum_{y_i \in G} f(xy_i^{-1})g(y_iy_1^{-1})h(y_1)+...+ \sum_{y_i \in G} f(xy_i^{-1})g(y_iy_n^{-1})h(y_n)$$

In both cases, I seem to have each of $f,g,h$ run through every element of $G$, but I don't believe that the same elements of $G$ is necessarily matched to each function. i.e. if I have $f(y_1)g(y_2)h(y_3)$ in one case, I still have each of $f(y_1), g(y_2), h(y_3)$ in the other, but not necessarily these terms multiplied together.

So I am not sure if it passes this ring axiom. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't convert to listing out elements of $G$, instead write it this way:
$$((f\ast g)\ast h)(x) = \sum_{y \in G}(f\ast g)(xy^{-1})h(y) = \sum_{y \in G}\left[\sum_{z \in G}f(xy^{-1}z^{-1})g(z)\right]h(y) = \sum_{y, z \in G}f(xy^{-1}z^{-1})g(z)h(y)$$
Now notice that $(xy^{-1}z^{-1})(z)(y) = x$ so this can be written as
$$\sum_{\substack{w, y, z \in G \\ wzy = x}}f(w)g(y)h(z).$$
In case you haven't seen this before, the double subscript means the summation ranges over all triples $(w, y, z) \in G^3$ that satisfy the condition $wzy = x$ (that condition implies $w = xy^{-1}z^{-1}$).  Try and do the same trick to $f\ast(g\ast h)$ and see what you get.

Comment: ah ok, thanks very much. Doing as you suggested, I got: $$\sum_{y,z \in G} f(xy^{-1})g(yz^{-1})h(z) $$ and thus up to renaming variables, it is indeed the same. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, I am also curious as to whether this ring is unital? By using the same form as you suggested, I seem to require a function $h$, such that $$\sum_{y,z \in G} f(y)h(z) = f(yz) $$ I'm finding it difficult to to determine that such a function $h$ exists, but I am also not convinced that there absolutely is not one. Is there a better way to look at this? Thanks again!

Comment: You're correct about the up to renaming variables thing.  As for a unit, try the function that's $1$ on the identity of $G$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much, that does seem to work as the identity. Sorry, just one more final final thing to confirm my understanding: Am I correct to say that $C(G)$ is an integral domain since (again using the form you suggested) since $$\sum_{y,z \in G} f(y)h(z) = 0 $$ iff each of $f(y_i)h(z_i) = 0$ (where $y_{i}h_{i} = x$) ? Thanks!

Comment: No, the sum could be zero even though the terms aren't.

Comment: Hi Jim, out of curiosity - would there be any circumstances for the underlying group G - that would make $C(G)$ an integral domain?

Comment: For a non-trivial group it's never an integral domain.  Consider the function that's just $1$ on all group elements and consider a function whose values when summed over the entire group yield zero.